# Perforce command line: How to view/edit unshelved files?

Tags: command-line, perforce, shelve, unshelve

Let's pretend that user A has a file called "Test.java" and it has:
`System.out.println("Hello")`

Now she changes the file to 
`System.out.println("How are you?")`

Then she decides to change it to:
`System.out.println("I'm fine")`

However, she doesn't want to submit the code yet, so she shelved both files with changelist 1234 and 5678.

Now user B wants to unshelve these changelists and test them, so he types:

`p4 unshelve -s 1234`

`p4 unshelve -s 5678`

My question is: where are these files located on user B's workspace? How can he run/modify these specific changelist?

Thank you!

Comment: The location of the files in user B's workspace will be entirely based on user B's client-spec (which specifies how depot paths are mapped to the local client).

Comment: @jamesdlin So does the unshelved "Test.java" file overwrite the "Test.java" file in user B's workspace?

Comment: Yes, it'll overwrite the existing copy.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you! If you can add add as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When user B unshelves the changeset, the unshelved files will be placed in the workspace according to user B's client-spec (which specifies how depot paths are mapped to the local client).  It'd be similar to if user A submitted the changeset and user B synced.

User B's versions of the files will be overwritten (unless they're already open for edit).